# Bypassing 2FA | Google Authenticator

Tags: security, authentication, math, google-authenticator

We have open source of Google Authenticator https://github.com/google/google-authenticator

Is there any way to reverse code generation process?

Imagine a situation:

We have `timestamp` and `generated code`. Even more, we have some pairs of this data.

Our task is to find the `secret code` or `code` which will be generated in the future.

How we can do that? Is there any known algorithm? I can't find anything about this. How many pairs of `code+timestamp` needed to solve this?

I could pay for right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are assuming that generated code comes from a function taking only `timestamp` as input, TOTP ietf paper shows that this based on HMAC-Based One-Time Password (HOTP), basically adding `timestamp` variable to the mix of a shared `secret` (symmetric encryption) input to a secure-enough hash function.

This shows that the best possible attack against the HOTP function is the brute force attack, which success rate is tied to maths behind implementation of a chosen hash function, in google Authenticator this is [SHA-256](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android/blob/master/java/com/google/android/apps/authenticator/crypto/CryptoModule.java)

It has been shown that the "level" of security associated with an encryption-related piece of code does not come from the secrecy of the code, this is why you dont need to reverse it in this case.